# Laravel Excel: how to get value of a cell?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I've loaded `.xls` file with [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel):

```
Excel::load('public/files/20160621.xls', function($reader) {
    // read a cell value
});
```

How do I read values of cells of the loaded excel file? Documentation seems to be unclear on that part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public function get()
{
    $excelFile ...
    return Excel::load($excelFile, function($doc) {

        $sheet = $doc->getSheetByName('data'); // sheet with name data, but you can also use sheet indexes.

        $sheet->getCell('A1');
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,0);           

    });
}
```

You're right, the documentation to read some cells is unclear.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sheet->getCell('A1')->setCell($sheet->getCell('B1')->getValue);
```

more info you can find [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519900)

Answer (score 0):

for read use this

```
public function reader($file)
{
    $excel=Excel::load($file, function($reader) {
        $reader->...//Document propities

        $sheet = $doc->getSheet(0); // sheet with index

        $cell=$sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();       

    })->toArray()//get();
   ...
   $cell=$excel->index//[row][col] Get formatted type(date,currency,calculated) cells
  ...
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.