# How to get value from A3 in Laravel Excel maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I use [Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) and I have data at ''A3'' cell. How to get it? I take this code is not working. It's show all data in that sheet.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074802/laravel-excel-how-to-get-value-of-a-cell)

```
 $sheet = $doc->getSheetByName('data'); 
 $sheet->getCell('A3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it too.You can check the array by dd, and get needed cell.

```
        public function loadExcel(Request $request)
        {
            $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();

            $records = \Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
                  $reader->noHeading();
            })->get()[0]->toArray();

            dd($records);

          //When you find the index of needed cell just $needed_cell = $records['index'];
    }
```